# How to set onClick selected value in input box using simple Java script

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have div, which has one input box and it generates some values in `<ol><li>` through ajax, now I wanted to select one of the values from `<li>` and set it in that input box using simple javascript.

```
<div id="abc">
     <input type="text" name="inputbox" id="inputboxID" class="inptBx"/>
     <ol>
    <li id="1">sam</li>
    <li id="2">joe</li>
    <li id="3">dan</li>
    <li id="4">tom</li>
    <li id="5">dick</li>
</ol>
</div>
```

Example : I have a div "abc" which has a inputbox, if I search something in it I get result in `<ol><li></li></ol>` tags(dropdown) through ajax, Now if I click on "tom", I want this value to be set in my inputbox.

Please suggest a javascript solution for this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you use jQuery, you could easily use this `$("#abc li").click(function() { $("#inputboxID").val($(this).text()); });` Here's a link with this script in action: http://ws10.dns.multinet.se/test/geotest.php

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function display(inPut)
{
var t=document.getElementById("inputboxID");
t.value = inPut;
}
</script>

<div id="abc">
      <input type="text" name="inputbox" id="inputboxID" class="inptBx"/>
 <ol>
     <li id="1" onClick="javascript:display(this.innerText)">sam</li>
     <li id="2" onClick="javascript:display(this.innerText)">joe</li>
     <li id="3" onClick="javascript:display(this.innerText)">dan</li>
     <li id="4" onClick="javascript:display(this.innerText)">tom</li>
     <li id="5" onClick="javascript:display(this.innerText)">dick</li>
 </ol> 
</div>
```

Comment: `<html><head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function display(inPut){
var t=document.getElementById("inputboxID");
t.value = inPut;
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="abc">
<form id="form1">
      <input type="text" name="inputbox" id="inputboxID" class="inptBx"/>
 <ol>
     <li id="1" onClick="javascript:display(this.innerText)">sam</li>
     <li id="2" onClick="javascript:display(this.innerText)">joe</li>
     <li id="3" onClick="javascript:display(this.innerText)">dan</li>
 </ol> 
 </form>
</div> </body>
</html> `  
Its not working, Please suggest..

Comment: this won't work in firefox or chrome. `this.innerText returns undefined in firefox and chrome`

Answer (score 1):

construct HTML like this while loading search results in div

```
<li id="4" onclick='$("#inputboxID").val(this.innerText)' >tom</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var i = 1; i < 6; i++)
    document.getElementById(i).addEventListener('click', loadText);

function loadText() {
    document.getElementById('inputboxID').value = this.innerHTML || this.innerText;
}
```

Also, make sure you fix the errors in your HTML markup:

```
<li id="3">dan</li>
<li id="4">tom</li>
```

You were missing the " after 3 and 4

#### 3 ways to include this script into your page so that it will execute properly:

[**http://jsfiddle.net/NmDW9/3/**](http://jsfiddle.net/NmDW9/3/) - Wrap javascript in head in a main function then call the main function at the end of HTML.

[**http://jsfiddle.net/NmDW9/6/**](http://jsfiddle.net/NmDW9/6/) - Include all javascript at the end of the `<body>`

[**http://jsfiddle.net/NmDW9/7/**](http://jsfiddle.net/NmDW9/7/) - Reference external .js file at the end of the `<body>`

Comment: why you are complicating things just add class on li or          $("#abc ul li").click(function(){ $("#inputboxID").val(this.text());});

Comment: He wants a javascript solution, not jQuery... and I'm not sure if he wants to maintain his HTML code exactly as is

Comment: no problem, i just edited the post, shorted the code a bit. the loadtext function is now 1 longer line instead of 3

Comment: It seems like when I add to my actual page its not working :(
Below is my actual script now -<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
 window.onload = function addSearchText()
 {
  document.getElementById("searchterms").value = 'Enter Search Term or Part #';
 }
 function removeSearchText()
 {
  document.getElementById("searchterms").value ="";
 }

for (var i = 1; i < 6; i++)
    document.getElementById(i).addEventListener('click', loadText);

function loadText() {
    document.getElementById('inputboxID').value = this.innerHTML || this.innerText;
}
</script>

Comment: Also In Body tag     
<form >
<input type="text" name="searchTerms" id="searchterms" class="inptBx" onfocus="removeSearchText();"/>
     
<html:image pageKey="img.common.catalogsearch_button" styleClass="btnGo" />
          <div id="SuggestionListDiv"></div> 
          </form>   On searching something in input box it generates values in li tag as mentioned above. Please suggest now

Comment: You need to include the javascript code after the HTML. Right before the `</body>` tag is where you should put your javascript code.

Comment: If you don't want to do that for whatever reason, and easy way to work around it is to wrap all of your javascript code in a function and then include a script tag at the bottom of your code to call that function, or write the javascript in an external file and use the script tag to import the file.

Answer (score 1):

If you use jQuery, you could use this snippet.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#abc li").click(function() { $("#inputboxID").val($(this).text()); });
</script>
```